# JSONpath in java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

JSON file

> [ { customerId:1}, { customerId:2 }, { customerId:3>} ]

in JAVA with

```
Response resp = when().get("link");
```

i received the json to resp file.

Now from the resp file - i'm tring to create a arrray - soo that all the values of the customerId is saved in that array using the below code

```
ArrayList list = resp
                    .then()
                    .contentType(ContentType.JSON) 
                    .extract()
                    .path(".customerId");
```

but its not working.

can someone help me out.?